# Displaying column joining two tables with subquery

Tags: sql

So I can't seem to figure out how to display a column that I am joining on with a subquery.

```
SELECT INSTRUCTOR, count(case when grade = 'A' then 1 end) totalA
FROM Grade_report AS gr, Section
WHERE Section.SECTION_ID=gr.SECTION_ID
AND (gr.GRADE='A')
GROUP by INSTRUCTOR ORDER by totalA DESC
```

I want to also select SECTION_ID and display that. But it says when I put it in the select line, Ambiguous column name 'SECTION_ID'.

Any help would be much appreciated thank you.

Comment: Use `gr.SECTION_ID`? There are two, `gr.SECTION_ID` and `Section.SECTION_ID`, you have to choose one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select gr.SECTION_ID or Section.SECTION_ID; the compiler doesn't know which one to choose.

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
SELECT INSTRUCTOR, gr.SECTION_ID, count(case when grade = 'A' then 1 end) totalA
FROM Grade_report AS gr, Section
WHERE Section.SECTION_ID=gr.SECTION_ID
AND (gr.GRADE='A')
GROUP by INSTRUCTOR, gr.SECTION_ID
ORDER by totalA DESC
```

Since the column names are the same in both tables, you have to specify table name (or alias) to avoid ambiguity (that's what the error is trying to tell you). You also have to include the new column into GROUP BY clause.